# How to change terminal settings by file configuration?

Tags: dconf

I want to use a text editor like `vim` to edit various configuration options such as the following:

[image]

In which configuration files are options like the above stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal configuration is not on a file, but in a gconf storage that cannot be edited directly. To change these settings you need to either use the graphical interface or open gconf-editor and change the values in `apps/gnome-terminal`.

You can also change those values via the command-line tool `gconftool-2`.